# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata not working on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, time-zone

I'm trying to change local timezone on Ubuntu 14.04 with the following commands.

```
$ echo Asia/Tokyo > /etc/timezone
$ dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Asia/Tokyo'
Local time is now:      Fri Apr 22 13:47:04 UTC 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Apr 22 13:47:04 UTC 2016.
```

However, localtime is still UTC not Asia/Tokyo.

I can change the timezone with `timedatectl`.

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo
$ timedatectl
  Local time: Fri 2016-04-22 23:07:29 JST
  Universal time: Fri 2016-04-22 14:07:29 UTC
    Timezone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
  NTP enabled: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: n/a
```

Once I change timezone with `timedatectl` then I can also change with dpkg-reconfigure to any timezone.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The method of [overwriting `/etc/timezone` no longer works](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/846989#846989).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was because of my stupid mistake. I was doing something like this in my script.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/ /etc/localtime
```

Changing to the following fixed the issue.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC  /etc/localtime
```